# How do I check to see if specific attribute changed upon rails update method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I update a record, I want the program to then see if a certain attribute was updated during that update save.

Specifically, after updating the record with the params, I want the program to see if the `@state_race.poll` parameter changed. If it did, I want to execute another code block.

How do I check to see if certain attribute changed?

My `@state_race.poll_changed?` isn't working.

```
  def update
    @state_race = StateRace.find(params[:id])
    if @state_race.update_attributes(state_race_params)
    puts 'race updated' 
        if  @state_race.poll_changed?
          puts 'poll changed' 
        else 
        end
    else
      render('edit')
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Why you not use callback for this ?

Comment: I assume using `puts` is just an example to make clear in what kind of events or states you are interested in. But unfortunately, it doesn't make clear what you actually want to achieve and what solution might fit your needs best – for example, callbacks in your model. Can you please elaborate on why you want to know about these attribute changes and what you actually want to do when that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution if to save the current value in other variable e.g

```
old_poll = @state_race.poll
```

then after the update, you can compare the values

```
if (old_poll == @state_race.poll)
```

The second solution is to use the gem [paper-trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail)

Comment: This is essentially why I ended up doing and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have put method `poll_changed?` after attributes has update successfully. To use this `polling_changed` I think you should you  `@state_race.assign_attributes(state_race_params)` and update item after or rewrite like store the value attribute `poll` and compare it with new value after updated.